# objcの クラスメソッド initialize相当の処理を Swiftで行う方法

Tags: swift, swift5

アーロン・ヒレガスの MAC OS X COCOA プログラミングのサンプルを Swiftで書き直していて、表題のところで詰まっています。

「各クラスは、何らかのメッセージを受信する前に initializeというメッセージを受け取ります」とあり、swiftでこのクラスメソッドを実装しようと以下のようなコードを書いてみたのですが、

```swift
import Foundation

class AClass : NSObject {
    override class func initialize() {
        print ("initialized")
    }

    func hello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

let a1 = AClass()
let a2 = AClass()

a1.hello()
a2.hello()

// 以下のような結果になってほしい
// initialized
// hello
// hello
```

結果は

> Method 'initialize() defines Objective-C class method 'initialize', which is not permitted by Swift

というエラーとなりました。

not permittedなのは仕方がないので別の方法を探しているのですが、何か良い方法はございませんか?

Answer (score 1):

Swiftの開発陣が`initialize`や`load`なんかのObjective-Cのクラスメソッドを禁止にしたのは、動作が実行環境や実行状態など非決定的な要因で変化してしまい、確実な動作保証をするのが難しいからと言うことだったと思います。(残念ながらその辺りの議論の跡をすぐに見つけることはできませんでした。)

「クラスの初期化」的な動作をさせたければ、初期化メソッドを用意して、アプリの起動時などに明示的にその初期化メソッドを呼んでやる、と言うのがSwift流と言うことになるのだろうと思います。

上記したように「最初のメソッドを呼び出す前(`initialize`)」(ただし、どの程度「前」かはよくわからない)なんて挙動をSwiftで再現することは難しいですが、「最初のインスタンスを使用する前」くらいでよければ、こんな感じで実現できます。

```
import Foundation

class AClass : NSObject {
    private static let initialization: Void = {
        print ("initialized")
    }()

    override init() {
        _ = AClass.initialization
    }

    func hello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}

let a1 = AClass()
let a2 = AClass()

a1.hello()
a2.hello()
```

実行結果

> ```
> initialized
> hello
> hello
> ```

Objective-CのコードをSwiftで書き直す、と言う練習は、Swift言語の学習の上でも効果的な手法の一つだと思いますが、「Swiftの文法でObjective-C的コードを書いてしまいがちになる」なんて弊害もあります。常に「これはSwift的なコードなのか?」なんてことを考える癖をつけると良いだろうと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。SwiftにふさわしいCocoaアプリケーションの書き方の作法が書籍化されると良いなと思うのですが、 BIG NERD RANCHも macOSより iOSに注力しているようでなかなか歯がゆいものがあります。

Comment: @Nunocky さん、コメントありがとうございます。iOSとmacOSの情報量の差については、開発者数の規模が圧倒的に違うので、致し方ないところ、と言う感じですね。また、書籍や著名サイトでiOSやmacOSのプログラミング記事を書いておられる大御所はObjective-C時代からのベテランが多く、「Swiftでそれはないでしょう」なんて記事が検索結果の上位に出たりします。(かく言う私もObjective-C時代からの生き残りではありますが。)ところであなたの「自分で調べた書き方」、正直言って「なんでこんなにややこしく見せる必要があるんだろう、ってコードになっていますが、本質的にはクラスのstatic変数の初期化が一度きりしか行われないことを利用しているだけ、つまり私の回答と同じことをやっているだけのものですね。

Comment: そうなんですねー。Swift難しいです...

Answer (score 0):

自分で調べた書き方

参考 : https://tech-blog.sgr-ksmt.org/2016/09/25/once_closure/

```swift
fileprivate typealias OnceClosure = (() -> Void)?
fileprivate func execute_once(_ execute: () -> Void) -> OnceClosure {
    execute()
    return {return nil}()
}

class AClass : NSObject {
    fileprivate static var exec_once : OnceClosure = execute_once {
        print("initialized")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        AClass.exec_once?()
    }

    func hello() {
        print("hello")
    }
}
```